# Angular 'Subject' does not subscribe in my router module

Tags: angular, typescript

So I am using a `canActivateFn` guard in my app where in it I am subscribing to a Subject. This Subject was created in a different service, and I am wondering why this subject won't subscribe (the subscription callback doesn't run). Take a look at the code.

Auth Service:

```js
 userCred = new Subject<boolean>()
 private handleAuthentication(email: string, id: string, tokenId: string) {
        let now = new Date().getTime() / 1000
        let user = new User(email, id, tokenId, (3600 + now))
        this.userCred.next(true) // I am sure this runs as the console.log runs.
        console.log("Does this run?") 
        this.user.next(user)
    }
```

App Route Module:

```js
const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = () => {
    let isAuthenticated: boolean
    let subscript = inject(AuthService).userCred.subscribe(bool => {
        // this line does not run.
        isAuthenticated = bool
    })
    console.log(inject(AuthService).userCred) // this doesn't run as undefined
    console.log(isAuthenticated) // this is undefined
    subscript.unsubscribe()
    return isAuthenticated ? true : false
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'recipes',
        component: RecipesComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        resolve: {data: () => inject(HttpService).fetchRecipes()},
        children: [
      // a bunch of child routes
]
}
```

Is perhaps the problem that the `AuthGuard` function runs before the `handleAuthentication` function or is that not relevent? Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

`CanActivateFn` accepts an `Observable` as return type, so just return your `Subject` !

```
const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = () => {
    let isAuthenticated: boolean
    return inject(AuthService).userCred
}
```

You solution didn't work because your `subscribe` was asynchronous (like it should always be assumed).

Comment: well, how will it know to evaluate to true or false then if we are just returning the subject? Sorry, I am actually knew to Angular

Comment: It will wait for the subject to return a value, a guard can be asynchronous.